# About positioning the speech bubble created by css

Tags: html, css

I am creating a webpage to show some Q&A for my students. I search online and find the following CSS may work to create a speech bubble with arrow on the left or on the right.

```
.speech {
  background: #efefef;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
          border-radius: 4px;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  line-height: 1.3;
  margin: 0px 30px 40px 160px;
  max-width: 88%;
  padding: 15px;
  position: relative;
  filter: drop-shadow(6px 4px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2));
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.onLeft::after {
  border-left: 11px solid transparent;
  border-right: 11px solid #efefef;
  border-top: 11px solid #efefef;
  border-bottom: 11px solid transparent;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: -20px;
  top: 8px;
  filter: drop-shadow(-2px -1px 0px black);
}

.onRight:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  border-left: 11px solid #efefef;
  border-right: 11px solid transparent;
  border-top: 11px solid #efefef;
  border-bottom: 11px solid transparent;
  right: -20px;
  top: 8px;
  filter: drop-shadow(2px -1px 0px black);
}
```

I can only host my website on an intranet and the following HTML will show something as seen in the capture

```
<div style="font-size: 12pt; margin-bottom: 20px; clear: both;">
  <img style="float: left; margin: 15px; src="logopic.png" width="120" />
  <div class="speech onLeft">
    Here is my example of a speech bubble created in CSS and HTML. 
  </div>
</div>
```

The width of the logopic.png is about 120px so I have my speech bubble shift about 160px to the right for some gap.

[image]

It looks good. But when I try to apply the speech bubble with the arrow on the right and with the logopic float to the right, the position is messed up

```
<div style="font-size: 12pt; margin-bottom: 20px; clear: both;">
  <img style="float: left; margin: 15px; src="logopic.png" width="120" />
    <div class="speech onLeft">
      Here is my example of a speech bubble created in CSS and HTML. </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div style="font-size: 12pt; margin-bottom: 20px; clear: both;">
  <img style="float: right; margin: 15px; src="logopic.png" width="120" />
  <div class="speech onRight">
    Here is my example of a speech bubble created in CSS and HTML. The arrow is on the right and the image is floating to the right. 
  </div>
</div>
```

The speech bubble is shifted all the way to the right. I tried to add shift to the "left" property (like left: -20px) on the div for the bubble, it doesn't help. Any idea to fix this issue?

[image]

---

Additional question: I am trying to modify the CSS with flexbox

```
.dia {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  flex-direction: row;
  padding: 1em;
  border-radius: 3px;
  max-width: 88%;
}
.speecher {
  margin-right: 30px;
  order: 0;
}

<div class="dia">
  <img class="speecher" src="logopic.jpg"/>
  <div class="speech onLeft">
    testing ... testing ... testing ... testing ... testing ... testing ... testing ... testing ... testing ... testing ... testing ... 
  </div>
</div>
```

I found that when the device screen is large, the CSS works well, the image aligned on the left and the speech bubble on the right. But when I use a mobile device or narrow the screen of the browser, it still layout on a row and the speech bubble becomes so slim. How could I change the layout based on the device/browser size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <title>index</title>
  <style type="text/css">
    body {
      margin: 0;
    }
    
    .speech {
      background: #efefef;
      -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
      border-radius: 4px;
      font-size: 1.2rem;
      line-height: 1.3;
      margin: 0px 30px 40px 190px;
      max-width: 80%;
      padding: 15px;
      position: relative;
      filter: drop-shadow(6px 4px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2));
      border: 1px solid black;
    }
    
    .onLeft::after {
      border-left: 11px solid transparent;
      border-right: 11px solid #efefef;
      border-top: 11px solid #efefef;
      border-bottom: 11px solid transparent;
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      left: -20px;
      top: 8px;
      filter: drop-shadow(-2px -1px 0px black);
    }
    
    .onRight:after {
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      border-left: 11px solid #efefef;
      border-right: 11px solid transparent;
      border-top: 11px solid #efefef;
      border-bottom: 11px solid transparent;
      right: -20px;
      top: 8px;
      filter: drop-shadow(2px -1px 0px black);
    }
    
    @media only screen and (max-width: 1366px) {
      .speech {
        margin: 0px 30px 40px 190px;
        max-width: 72%;
      }
    }
    
    @media only screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
      .speech {
        margin: 0px 30px 40px 190px;
        max-width: 64%;
      }
    }
    
    @media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
      .speech {
        margin: 0px 30px 40px 190px;
        max-width: 51%;
      }
    }
    
    @media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
      .speech {
        margin: 0px 30px 40px 190px;
        max-width: 45%;
      }
    }
    
    @media only screen and (max-width: 575px) {
      .speech {
        margin: 0px 30px 40px 190px;
        max-width: 30%;
      }
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div style="font-size: 12pt; margin-bottom: 20px; clear: both;">
    <img style="float: left; margin: 15px;" src="https://www.w3schools.com/images/picture.jpg" width="120 " />
    <div class="speech onLeft ">Here is my example of a speech bubble created in CSS and HTML.</div>
  </div>
  <div style="font-size: 12pt; margin-bottom: 20px; clear: both; ">
    <img style="float: right; margin: 15px;" src="https://www.w3schools.com/images/picture.jpg" width="120" />
    <div class="speech onRight">Here is my example of a speech bubble created in CSS and HTML. The arrow is on the right and the image is floating to the right.</div>
  </div>
</body>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: ah ... that's what I need. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would forget about `float` here. If you turn the container into a Flexbox container, everything will be extremely easy. You won't have to use that 160px left margin.

In the second case, if you can't change the order, you'll be able to do it as well with Flexbox (using `order`). If you need the exact code to solve this, let me know, although I think you can manage to solve it.

See some tricks here:
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Thanks. Flexbox works. I am using align-items: flex-start;
 AND flex-direction: row; and it works well. However, I find an issue that if I use "flex-direction: row", when the device/screen size is small, it still layout the speech and the image in row so the speech bubble becomes so slim. I wonder if there is any way to change the layout based on the screen size such that for wide screen, it aligns by row and aligns by column otherwise.

Comment: You can set a breakpoint and change to `flex-direction: column` for smaller screens. You will also probably need to set `align-self` to flex-start for .onLeft and to flex-end  for .onRight